# What is the minimum spacing between inductors to prevent cross talk?

Tags: inductor

I have to put three inductors in a box. The inductors are air core with a diameter of 6in and a height of 4.5in. The value is going to be about 16uH. The inductors will see about 50Arms continuous at about 4kHz. Each inductor is on a leg of a 3 phase output.

How far apart should the inductors be to reduce the cross talk to a minimum?

Are there any rule of thumb for spacing such inductors?

Comment: Can you place them all orthogonal to each other, or do you need to place them oriented in parallel?

Comment: *How far apart should the inductors be to reduce the cross talk to a minimum?* Then they should be at an infinite distance from eachother. But that is not the answer you're looking for. What you're looking for is the engineer's answer: *what is far enough* ?

Comment: Much of the work involving air core inductors is done in the RF field. I don't recall reading a paper that goes near 4kHz. At high frequency, shielding can be considered using Eddy currents to generate opposing magnetic fields (Lenz' law) to lessen the intensity of the magnetic field beyond the shield. But 4kHz is such a low rate of change that I don't think you'd get much of a useful effect there. Photon's suggestion about them positioned perpendicularly (AND symmetrically aligned, not offset) can help with air core inductors. Up to 3 only. But then the rest will have to be distance, I think.

Comment: @jonk How would you arrange the three? Every layout i can think of is a compromise.

Comment: @vini_i all of engineering is compromises.

Comment: @vini_i: perpendicularly and symmetrically. Assume just two for now: You can supply a coil with 4kHz power and observe the output voltage of another nearby, unpowered coil with a very high impedance meter. Minimize that induced output. Or measure the inductance of a coil with the other coil unconnected. Then measure the inductance of the same coil again, but this time with the other coil shorted. Minimize the change in inductance. Now add the 3rd coil and repeat in all combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A coil will produce a field (Bx) at some distance along the centre axis like this: -

[image]

Where

[image]

n = number of turns, I = current and x and r are dimensions of the coil and spacings.

So how much field can you suffer with cross coupling. Clearly you will get some at any distance but, beyond a point (x >> r) the field falls as distance cubed.

It's also a reasonable assumption to make that at those sorts of distances, the field received will tend to be constant in the plane of the receiving coil therefore you can calculate total flux entering the coil and, using the frequency of your signals calculate rate of change of flux.

E (induced voltage) = N\$\dfrac{d\Phi}{dt}\$ where N = number of turns of receive coil.

So, there are formulas and little rules of thumb. How much induced voltage you can suffer is beyond my knowledge.